# How do I prevent this javascript from being evaluated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, execution, evaluation

I am trying to build a web based code editor, and load javascript into a textarea value and I discovered quite by accident that the page is evaluating the code.

```
var url = 'local.js';
var timestamp = new Date().getUTCMilliseconds();
$.get(url, {r:timestamp}, function(data) {
    $("#scriptview").val(data);
    $("#editor").slideDown();
});
```

How do I prevent the GET request from evaluating the code?  I am getting the source directly from a local file.

UPDATE:
Changing the code to add the dataType fixed this problem.  I couldn't get the $.get syntactic sugar just right so I'm using $.ajax

```
var url = 'local.js';
var timestamp = new Date().getUTCMilliseconds();
$.ajax({url:url, data: {r:timestamp}, success: function(data) {
       $("#scriptview").val(data);
       $("#editor").slideDown();
       return false;
}, dataType: "text"});
```

I still don't understand why the code inside the called file was being executed, I'm not appending to the body in a script tag or anything.

Comment: Add "text" as the dataType https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/#jQuery-get-url-data-success-dataType

Comment: @freedomn-m make it an answer

Comment: Hold on here, how exactly will the `$.get()` implicitly evaluate the JavaScript?

Comment: I'm with @Pointy I don't think this code is the culprit. There's something else you're doing with the textarea value that's evaluating it. Are you putting it into `.html()` of something?

Comment: Add an `alert("local.js")` as the very first line in your page.  It's possible that you're inadvertently loading it (eg through a bundle)

Comment: adding the dataType as text prevented the problem.  And no, I'm not doing anything with the data other than set the val() of the textarea.  But even when commenting that out the source javascript is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jQuery.ajax` accepts a `dataType` parameter. Setting it explicitly will:

- Set the `Accept` header
- Ignore the `Content-Type` of the response and parse the data as the format you say.

If you don't set it, then jQuery will infer the data type from the `Content-Type` of the response. This is *usually* a good thing!

In this case, you are requesting JavaScript (which will come with a `Content-Type: text/javascript` response header) but don't want it to be treated as JavaScript. jQuery does support `"script"` as a data type!

Set the `dataType` (to `"text"`) to override the default handling.

(Credit to @freedomn-m for spotting the issue)